# Colocar la fecha y hora en el nombre del archivo excel (.xlsx) con Datatables

Tags: datatables

Código que debes colocar para que tus archivo Excel tenga por nombre la fecha y hora de tu PC.

Se le pueden poner el resto de botones después de la coma, pero siempre dentro de buttons:

```
    buttons: [
  {
    extend: "excelHtml5",
    text: "Excel-xlsx",
    titleAttr: "Exportar a Excel",
    filename: function () {
      var date = new Date();
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
      var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
      var hours = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
      var minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
      return (
        "Seleccionados_" +
        year +
        "-" +
        month +
        "-" +
        day +
        "_" +
        hours +
        "-" +
        minutes
      );
    },

],
```